# Android canvas - setWillNotDraw(false) not working

Tags: android, canvas

The following code it's an activity class with a custom view class. This code is the only working example of canvas for me.

I just need to recall in loop the onDraw function (like animationframe in javascript canvas2d).
I can always use timers to make a call but maybe there is some low level nice way for that. I'm a newbie in Android development.

Question update: I use class name instead of instance name. No need for static for sure.
***Current status : crash on activate activity.***

```
public class CanvasNativeSurface extends AppCompatActivity {

private GoogleApiClient client;


private myview myView;

private Handler mHandler;

class myview extends View
{

    private void init() {
    }

    public myview(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    int x=80;
    int y=180;

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

         x=80;

         y = y + 1;

        int radius=40;
        Paint paint=new Paint();
        // Use Color.parseColor to define HTML colors
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
        canvas.drawCircle(x,y, radius, paint);
    }

    public  void move()
    {
        y= y+30;// 30 is value for testing
        // change it to whatever you want.
        invalidate();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ViewGroup view1;
    view1 = (ViewGroup) findViewById( R.id.activity_canvas_native_surface  );
    /// setContentView(R.layout.activity_canvas_native_surface );
    setContentView(new myview(this));

    mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);

}


private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        myView.move();
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
```

y = y + 1; Must push object to the bottom. Circle has no movement.

Catch in log: 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void....CanvasNativeSurface$myview.move()' on a null object reference

Also Android Studio on mouseover it says: myView never assingned

Comment: Why do you need `setWillNotDraw(false);`

Comment: I want recall onDraw .

Comment: Did you try debugging and find out how many times `invalidate();` is called and also you don't need `setWillNotDraw(false);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MyView.jav // separate file

```
public class MyView extends View
{

    private   int x=80,y=180,radius=40;
    private Paint paint;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {

        paint=new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawCircle(x,y, radius, paint);

    }

    public void move()
    {
      y= y+30;// 30 is value for testing
      // change it to whatever you want.
      invalidate();

    }
}
```

And in your activity you can do something like

```
private MyView myView;
private Handler mHandler;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    myView = new MyView(this);
    setContentView(myView);

    mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);

}

private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        myView.move();
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
```

Finally don't forget to

```
mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(mRunnable);
```

When you want to stop.

As i said earlier you don't need  `setWillNotDraw(false);` and your constructor is called only once.

You probably need a timer mechanism to move the circle every second or something. I hope you got the idea and you can make changes accordingly.

If you are looking for animation

```
public class MyView extends View
{

    private int x=80,y=180,radius=40;
    private Paint paint;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {

        paint=new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawCircle(x,y, radius, paint);

    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

     public void setStateOnObject(){

        // 900 is the end value
        ObjectAnimator animateBottom = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this,"y",y,900);
        animateBottom.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                postInvalidate();
            }
        });
        AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        animatorSet.play(animateBottom);
        animatorSet.setDuration(5000).start();
    }
}
```

And instead of handler you would do

```
  myView.setStateOnObject();
```

Comment: One more question please. I got  :error: non-static method move() cannot be referenced from a static context . If i make method static i cant access to the y for example ...

Comment: Move method is not static.  Also I don't see the need for static anywhere

Comment: You can use a getter and setter get rid of static. I don't quite understand the need for static modifier

Comment: @NikolaLukic pls look at my post again . You have this `setContentView(new myview(this));` But its not assigned and you can't call any method in myview class. Copy paste the code here and you will see it will work. In my case Myview is in a separate file